# How to authenticate AWS EBS (Beanstalk) on ECS (Container Storage)? AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs, amazon-ebs

I'm new to using AWS EBS and ECS, so please forgive me if I ask a question which might be obvious for others. To the issue:

I've configured EBS and ECS in the same AWS cloud region. I've pushed my container and can see the image in ECS. The EBS environment has been built using a `Dockerrun.aws.json` pointing to the ECS. During the build of the EBS I get the following error:

```
2020/11/02 20:50:25.858567 [INFO] authenticate with ECR if the image is in an ECR repo
2020/11/02 20:50:25.858582 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --registry-ids 731178912345 --region eu-west-1
2020/11/02 20:50:28.355911 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to authenticate with ECR for registry 731178912XXX in eu-west-1: Command /bin/sh -c aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --registry-ids 731178912XXX --region eu-west-1 failed with error exit status 255. Stderr:
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:sts::731178912XXX:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-0bff9b5324348ea71 is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
```

I read somewhere that the identify is automatically passed in to process the authentication. I couldn't find any indication on what to do to resolve the issue. Maybe someone could help me out?

After adding the permission as discussed I get these:

```
2020/11/03 09:17:46.490399 [INFO] pull docker image if update is not false in Dockerrun.aws.json
2020/11/03 09:17:46.490431 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker pull 731178912XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/user/project:latest
2020/11/03 09:17:46.576648 [WARN] failed to execute command: docker pull 731178912XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/user/project:latest, retrying...
2020/11/03 09:17:46.576673 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker pull 731178912XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/user/project:latest
2020/11/03 09:17:46.659379 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to pull docker image: Command /bin/sh -c docker pull 731178912XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/user/project:latest failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 731178912XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/user/project, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: arn:aws:sts::731178912XXX:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-0aa453e0d44cdfa90 is not authorized to perform: ecr:BatchGetImage on resource: arn:aws:ecr:eu-west-1:731178912XXX:repository/user/project
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` instance role does not have permissions to execute `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken`.

You can address this, by adding an `inline policy` to the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that more permissions may be needed after this one. You can add them in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where exactly would I add this? In the `Dockerrun.aws.json` or elsewhere?

Comment: @spekulatius Go to IAM console -> Roles and search for `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`. There you will have option of `Add inline policy`.

Comment: That moved it forward a bit: I added the permission and rebuild the environment. It still fails to pull the container image - with a different error message this time tho. Any ideas on what the reason could be @Marcin?

Comment: @spekulatius As I wrote in the answer, you may need to add more permissions. This time: `ecr:BatchGetImage`. I don't know how many is required. Just add them as you go.

Comment: Thank you Marcin, looking through the logs I've found one more missing permission. After adding it as well it worked! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Marcin, maybe you got an idea on my follow-up issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664476/aws-ebs-runs-into-504-gateway-time-out too?