# AWS EBS runs into "504 Gateway Time-out"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to using AWS EBS and ECS, so please bear with me if I ask questions that might be obvious for others. To the issue:

I've got a single-container Node/Express application that runs on EBS. The local docker container works as expected. On EBS, I can access one endpoint of the API and get the expected output. For the second endpoint, which runs longer (around 10-15 seconds) I get no response and run after 60 seconds into a time out: "504 Gateway Time-out".

I wonder how I would approach debugging this as I can't connect to the container directly? Currently there isn't any debugging functionality in the code included either as I'm not sure what the best node approach for a EBS container is - any recommendations are highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why you can't connect to the EB instance? Also what do you mean by the second-endpoint? Which endpoint?

Comment: Hey Marcin, with endpoint I mean a Restful API endpoint - kinda of a page in app. The application has two: a simple one that works without any issues and one more complex one that fails for whatever reason. So the container itself works. 

What do you mean with connect to the EB instance? Log into the container? Not sure how to do this.

Comment: Yes, you could ssh into instance, and check from inside if your contains work, do the endpoints respond using `curl`.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure how I would ssh into it. simply `ssh URL` doesn't work - I haven't even defined an SSH key anywhere yet. Could you point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the EC2 instances running on EBS in your AWS, and you can choose to give them IP addresses in your EBS options. That will let you SSH directly into them if you need to.

Otherwise check the keepAliveTimeout field in your server (the value returned by app.listen() of you're using express).

I got a decent number of 504s when my Node server timeout was less than my load balancer timeout.

Comment: Hey Adam, I've added `keepAliveTimeout` (and `headersTimeout`) as recommended here https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2019/04/25/keep-alive-timeout/ with 61 seconds and 65 seconds. Same behavior. I couldn't find the place to see the IP on the AWS dashboard - pretty confusing UI.

Comment: You have to set the option in EBS to have your EC2 instances have public IPs. I can't remember where that config option is, but I think it's the same place you choose security groups and VPCs. Sorry it wasn't the timeout thing, that would have been a nice, simple solution!

Comment: As far as I know I don't run an explicit EC2 instance - just a single docker container with EBS. Sure there is a machine below, but can I get to it?

Comment: Behind the scenes, EBS runs on EC2. You should be able to see those instances in your EC2 panel (not within the EBS interface).

Comment: Interesting - I can't see any in the region: the resources show all zero, except of a security group.

Answer (score 0):

Your application takes longer than expected (> 60 seconds) to respond, so either nginx or the Load Balancer terminates your request.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974920/878244)