# Elasticbeanstalk returns "504 Gateway Timeout"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an endpoint in my API which takes some time to return a response (>1 min).

I have deployed my API to Elasticbeanstalk and now when I try to access it I get a 504 Gateway Timeout from Nginx

```
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Timeout errors such as yours should ideally fixed by improvement to the software itself, but if it cannot be done for any reason, then you can increase the timeout of your nginx and Load Balancer.

In previous versions of Amazon Linux you would need to deploy your code with custom nginx configuration inside a directory named .ebextensions

With Amazon Linux 2 things are quite the same with a slight difference, instead of using the `.ebextensions` you need to use the `.platform` folder for your platform's configurations.

So, inside your app's intended ElasticBeanstalk package create the following structure -

```
eb-package
└── src
└── .ebextensions
└── .platform
    └── nginx
        └── conf.d
            └── timeout.conf
```

And add the following content to your `timeout.conf` file

```
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
send_timeout 600;
```

You should be aware that in some cases you'll need to increase your Load Balancer's timeout by either manually configuring it with the AWS Console (Under EC2) or by providing a configuration file inside the `.ebextensions` directory

For example (Note: this configuration will vary by the type of Load Balancer which you use):

```yaml
option_settings:
   - namespace: aws:elb:policies
     option_name: ConnectionSettingIdleTimeout
     value: 300
```

See Classic Load Balancer vs Application Load Balancer configuration

In AWS's docs (per 08/29/2021) the newer Application Load Balancer has no default timeout.
The Classic Load Balancer has a timeout of 60 seconds.

`aws:elb:policies`
vs
`aws:elbv2:loadbalancer`

For more info, see

- [Extending Elastic Beanstalk Linux platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)
- [AWS Environments Options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html)

Comment: "See Classic Load Balancer vs Application Load Balancer configuration

In AWS's docs (per 08/29/2021) the newer Application Load Balancer has no default timeout. The Classic Load Balancer has a timeout of 60 seconds." 

I just changed this config on LoadBalancers and everything works.

Comment: Going crazy. I have a single instance environment, no proxy server, Docker, and STILL a 60 second timeout. I can't get around it no matter what I do, no matter what ELB setting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was useful. I was struggling with this error from long time.

Comment: @JoshuaWolff how was it going now?

Comment: @TanDat It was almost certainly an AWS bug. It was fixed miraculously on its own after updating the deployment version (when a new one came out) and I haven't had trouble since. Now, I can go up to 300 sec, no problem.